# How to force background color in gmail for Dark Mode?

Tags: css, gmail, background-color, darkmode, html-templates

I am working on HTML email templates.I am stuck with forcing background color and text color attributes for Dark mode.My normal inline css is background-color:#f2f2f2 and color:#191919.But in dark mode I want background-color:#ff5f00 and color:#ffffff.

I am able to achieve the same in outlook using @media but as said in various blogs to use blend modes for gmail,I am not able to achieve the same.Can anyone help with a HTML template or HTML code?

CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
    <meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark">
    <style>
        :root {
            color-scheme: light dark;
            supported-color-schemes: light dark;
        }

        body {
            font-family: Arial;
            background-color: #eee;
            color: #111;
        }

        .Greetings_section {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            padding: 40px 20px;
        }

        .darkmodecustom {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            color: #191919;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        .bg-orange {
            background-color: #FF5F00;
            border-color: 1px solid #ff5f00;
        }

        .button_text {
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        .darkimage {
            display: none;
        }

        a[href] {
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
            body {
                background-color: #111;
                color: #eee;
            }

            .Greetings_section {
                background-color: #f2f2f2;
                padding: 20px 10px;
            }

            .darkmodecustom {
                background-color: #f2f2f2;
                color: #eee;
                padding: 5px;
            }

            .bg-orange {
                background-color: #FF5F00;
                border-color: 1px solid #FF5F00;
            }

            .button_text {
                color: #eee;
            }
        }

        [data-ogsc] .body {
            background-color: #111;
            color: #eee;
        }

        [data-ogsc] .Greetings_section {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            padding: 40px 20px;
        }

        [data-ogsc] .darkmodecustom {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            color: white;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        [data-ogsc] .bg-orange {
            background-color: #FF5F00;
            border-color: 1px solid #ff5f00;
        }

        [data-ogsc].button_text {
            color: #eee;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="body">
    <table role="presentation" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <table role="presentation" width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="background-color:azure;padding:10px">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 5px;">Dark mode - System (User Agent Styles)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" bgcolor="transparent" style="padding:0px; font-size:0px; line-height:0px;" valign="top" width="100%">
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                                                <![endif]-->
                            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding:0; max-width:600px; font-size:0px; line-height:0px; background-color:#ffffff" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="left" class="mobile-padding Greetings_section" style="padding:0px 24px 20px 24px; font-size:0px; line-height:0px" valign="top">
                                        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="left" class="mobile-padding Greetings_section" style=" font-size:0px; line-height:0px;" valign="top">
                                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="left" class="fs14lh16 darkmodecustom" style="padding:0px 0px 8px 0px; font-family:'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, 'SF Pro', 'Corbel', 'Microsoft Sans Serif', 'Segoe UI', sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height:24px; font-weight:600; color:#191919" valign="top">
                                                                <span class="fs14lh16" style="font-family:'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, 'SF Pro', 'Corbel', 'Microsoft Sans Serif', 'Segoe UI', sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height:24px; font-weight:600; color:#191919"> Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero, facilis assumenda soluta id ut labore ipsa aliquam reprehenderit</span>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="left" style="padding:0px; font-size:0px; line-height:0px" valign="top">
                                                                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="left" class="fs12lh14 darkmodecustom" style="padding:8px 0px 0px 0px; font-family:'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, 'SF Pro', 'Corbel', 'Microsoft Sans Serif', 'Segoe UI', sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:19px; font-weight:400; color:#191919" valign="top" width="15">
                                                                            <span class="fs12lh14" style="font-family:'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, 'SF Pro', 'Corbel', 'Microsoft Sans Serif', 'Segoe UI', sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:19px; font-weight:400; color:#191919">&bull;</span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td align="left" class="fs12lh14" style="padding:8px 0px 0px 0px; font-family:'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, 'SF Pro', 'Corbel', 'Microsoft Sans Serif', 'Segoe UI', sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:19px; font-weight:400; color:#191919" valign="top">
                                                                            <span class="fs12lh14" style="font-family:'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, 'SF Pro', 'Corbel', 'Microsoft Sans Serif', 'Segoe UI', sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:19px; font-weight:400; color:#191919">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="left" class="fs12lh14 darkmodecustom" style="padding:8px 0px 0px 0px; font-family:'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, 'SF Pro', 'Corbel', 'Microsoft Sans Serif', 'Segoe UI', sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:19px; font-weight:400; color:#191919" valign="top" width="15">
                                                                            <span class="fs12lh14" style="font-family:'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, 'SF Pro', 'Corbel', 'Microsoft Sans Serif', 'Segoe UI', sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:19px; font-weight:400; color:#191919">&bull;</span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td align="left" class="fs12lh14" style="padding:8px 0px 0px 0px; font-family:'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, 'SF Pro', 'Corbel', 'Microsoft Sans Serif', 'Segoe UI', sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:19px; font-weight:400; color:#191919" valign="top">
                                                                            <span class="fs12lh14" style="font-family:'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, 'SF Pro', 'Corbel', 'Microsoft Sans Serif', 'Segoe UI', sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:19px; font-weight:400; color:#191919">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="left" style="padding:16px 0px 0px 0px; font-size:0px; line-height:0px" valign="top">
                                                                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="left" valign="middle">
                                                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="bg-orange" width="auto">
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                                                                                        <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                                                        <![endif]-->
                                                                                    <td align="center" class="h32px fs12lh14 bg-orange" width="144" height="44" style="color:#191919; font-family:'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, 'SF Pro', 'Corbel', 'Microsoft Sans Serif', 'Segoe UI', sans-serif; font-size:16px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height:16px; font-weight:600; padding:0" valign="middle">
                                                                                        <a class="fs12lh14 button_text" href="#" style="text-decoration:none; display:block; padding:8px 16px 8px 16px;" target="_blank">Lorem ipsum dolor </a>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                                                                                        <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                                                        <![endif]-->
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                            </table>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <![endif]-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome! Please show a [mre] of what you have so far. Would it be possible for you to provide a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/11107541)?

Comment: Have you checked e.g. through caniemail whether the CSS you are using is supported on gmail?

Comment: Kindly check this for code
https://jsfiddle.net/Poojajainapp/0qc6ynt5/1/

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code in the question itself.

Comment: Added Kindly check the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` media query and creating a couple classes. Then apply those classes to the elements that should have the darkmode style applied.

Example:

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .darkmode-bg {
    background-color: #ff5f00 !important;
  }
  .darkmode-color {
    color: #ffffff !important;
  }
}
```

It's hard to answer this without code to test, but that would be what I'd suggest. [Source](https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-dark-mode-for-email-marketers/).

It's also recommended to add these meta tags in your `<head>` tag to ensure that Dark Mode is enabled in your email for users that have Dark Mode turned on.

```html
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
<meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark">
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) Works only with Outlook,and Outlook puts some inline code with impotant tag ignoring all the css for background-color.@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark),doesn't work with Gmail.

Comment: Hello, I know this was a while ago but just wondering if you ever found a way to target gmail in dark mode? I'm running into the same issues.